# Jquery Address plugin: how to avoid history change?

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, jquery-address

**Short question:**

I'm trying to make that in a given page (uses tabs) back button doesn't change page URL (history). It is, I need when user press *back button* the tab changes, but not the URL displayed. How can I do that with the Address plugin?

**Long question:**

In addition to the explained above, I have to say I'm using the address plugin like this:

```
$.address.strict(false);
$.address.externalChange(function(e) {
    changePageFunction(e.value);
});
```

Inside this *changePageFunction()* I'm setting `$.address.title(the_title);` and `$.address.value(the_value);`. What I've tried is to change the direct call to *changePageFunction()* by something like this:

```
$.address.externalChange(function(e) {
    if (!isTabsPage) {
        changePageFunction(e.value);
    } else {
        changeTab();
    }
});
```

This works, but URL displayed is changed (goes back one position for each back button pressed).

I cannot:

- add a different URL to each tab (like in $.address samples)
- change address plugin for other similar
- change current paging system (a bit complex)

The idea is that if *isTabsPage* is true then the *changeTab()* function will work, if not, the current method will work ($.address history managed)

Is there any way to freeze the history?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HTML5 has a native history object to handle this.  You'll need to use its pushState function as the user changes tabs and handle its popState event when the user navigates forwards/backwards.  There is a wonderful polyfill for older browsers by @balupton [here](https://github.com/balupton/History.js/).

Answer (score 0):

You have no control over the browser back button. If you set the hash in the first place, the browser will ALWAYS be able to change the hash with the back button. Your only option is to grab the hash and change it manually, which is going to break your back button functionality by making loops etc.

This has NOTHING to do with jQuery. All jQuery does is manipulate the location.hash property.

http://www.ezineasp.net/post/Javascript-Location-Hash-with-Example.aspx

why would you want to do this? Your application state should be reflected in the hash.